# What possible symbols could be generated when converting a buffer to a hex string?

Tags: node.js, probability

I want to know the probability of getting the same secret if it was generated with the following function

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const generateSecret = () => {
  const buffer = await crypto.randomBytes(8);
  return buffer.toString('hex').slice(0, 4);
}
```

But I'm not sure what range of symbols can be created with `buffer.toString('hex')`. Is it all the alpha-numeric symbols?
In this case it's 62 symbols (lowercase + uppercase + digits).
If there's 62 symbols there're (62 + 4 - 1)!/ (4! * (62 - 1)!) possible combinations (with repetitions) or 677040. So, the probability in this case is `1/677040 * 100` which is about `0.00014`%

Answer (score 0):

Hex is only going to give you 16 possible characters, 0-9 and A-F. So that's `16^4` possibilities, `65,536`.

You can get more by using `toString(36)` which will give you 36 possibilities in each character. A base 64 converter will give you 64 characters.

If you want something random, you need to have a lot more than 4 characters (the `slice(0, 4)`.